# No puedo agrupar elementos de una tabla con groupby pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un Dataframe de pandas con la siguiente estructura

## Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype

---

0   hora    2747 non-null   timedelta64[ns] 
1   Device  2747 non-null   int64          
2   A       2747 non-null   float64        
3   B       2747 non-null   float64        
4   C       2747 non-null   object

['hora']  ['Device']     ['A']      ['B']               ['C']
0    0 days 11:33:00       1  1.389   25.0           0.439
1    0 days 11:33:00       2  2.530  219.0   2.530021.5000
2    0 days 11:33:11       1  1.390   24.9           0.442
3    0 days 11:33:12       2  2.100  319.1   2.100021.7000
4    0 days 11:33:23       1  1.388   24.8           0.443
...              ...     ...    ...    ...             ...
2742 0 days 16:02:59       1  1.419   23.9           0.478
2743 0 days 16:02:59       2  0.430   84.1   0.430024.3000
2744 0 days 16:03:11       1  1.422   23.9            0.48
2745 0 days 16:03:11       2  1.680  168.6   1.680024.2000
2746 0 days 16:03:23       1  1.426   23.9           0.482

[2747 rows x 5 columns]

Necesito separarla en dos grupos, los de Device 1 y 2, pero al ejecutar con .groupby no muestra nada.

print(df.groupby(df['Device'] == 1))

<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x00000193A5904820>

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Lo que muestras, es lo que debe mostrar el resultado de hacer df.groupby. No debe ser ni es un dataframe. Hay formas de acceder a cada grupo, te recomiendo leer la documentación para averiguar como.

Comment: Ademas, al poner una condición en el groupby, los grupos son true (es decir, todas las filas que cumplen la condición,) y False (las que no la cumplen, que son todos los datos cuyo device no es 1)

Comment: Si lo que deseas es obtener las filas de grupo 1 y grupo 2, mejor utiliza `loc`

Answer (score 2):

Como tal vez ya te comentaron, lo que estás buscando imprimir no es un dataframe. Te recomiendo usar un notebook de Jupyter, ahí te será más sencillo explorar los módulos y ver la documentación de las funciones.

Te pongo un código de ejemplo de cómo podrías realizar agregaciones con un dataframe como el que comentas:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np

num_samples = 1000
sample = [{
    "hora":np.random.choice(range(0,24)),
    "Device":np.random.choice(range(0,5)),
    "A":np.random.uniform(0,2.5),
    "B":np.random.uniform(0,2.5),
    "C":np.random.uniform(0,2.5),
} for _ in range(num_samples)]
pandas_example = pd.DataFrame(sample)
pandas_example
```

Este dataframe se vería así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para agrupar puedes usar el siguiente código:

```
pandas_example.groupby("Device").agg( num_rows = ( "hora", "count"),avg_a=( "A", "mean"), avg_b=( "B", "mean"), min_c=( "C", "min"), custom_c = ("C", lambda el: 2*min(el)))
```

Resultado código 2:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes buscar además más documentación acerca de la función group by.

Comment: Bienvenidó a [es.so], has creado una primera respuesta bien documentada y con un ejemplo funcional, voto a favor! Saludos!